# Use a predictive model to make a recommendation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I used the `RandomForestClassifier` from `sklearn` to create a predictive model. Now I have a model with decent accuracy.

Now I want to make a recommendation of what inputs should be used in order to maximize the chances of getting the value that I want. I got the weights from `feature_importances_`, but I don't know how to translate this into a recommendation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

The RandomForestClassifier's feature_importances_ returns an array with numbers for each of your features. The higher the number in the array is, the higher the importance of the feature. You can match this to your features by using

```
df.columns
```

to get the features and then match them to the importances. You can then use a loop to go through and make a dictionary to match features to numbers. Then you can find the highest numbers and recommend those features. Hope this helped!